# Retrofit add header with token and id

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I have a problem with getting authenticated user. Before it I got token and user id. Now i need to get user from server using access token and id. 
[I have header format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQ87Y.png)

Now I'am trying to add header with user token and id using interceptor.

My code:

```
Interceptor interceptor = new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                    .addHeader("authorization", token) <-??
                    .addHeader("driver_id", id) <-??
                    .build();
            return chain.proceed(newRequest);
        }
    };
    OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    okHttpBuilder.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = okHttpBuilder.build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();
```

Interface:

```
@GET("driver/v1/driver")
Call<Driver> getAuthorizedDriver();
```

Different variants throws 401 error, don't know what to do
Log:

```
I/Response code: 401
I/Response message: Unauthorized`
```

Comment: DId you try using @Headers("token:" + TOKEN) above your @GET ?

Comment: I always need new token value. Thank you

Comment: another way would be to pass the token and the id via the getAuthorizedDriver()

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got it.
It's must look like:

```
@GET("driver/v1/driver")
Call<Driver> getAuthorizedDriver(@Header("authorization") String auth);
```

And auth:

```
Call<Driver> call = apiInterface.getAuthorizedDriver("Token token=" + token + ", driver_id=" + id);
```

Comment: ok, if that worked: great for you. but one minor criticism. next time please provide a proper api doc. the one you provided suggested that you need 2 parameters instead of one that is combined out of two values. anyways: have a nice day, and continue coding :)

Answer (score 12):

Try to pass the header values via the method call:

```
@GET("driver/v1/driver")
Call<Driver> getAuthorizedDriver(@Header("authorization") String token,
                                 @Header("driver_id") Integer id);
```

You also wouldn't have to deal with this huge chunk of Interceptor code