# Android Retrofit Upload File with authorization Body

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I'm using retrofit to connect to server which needs authorization token in POST Data. Example For the request:

```
https://adress/inboxes
POST data:
token=jasdf807gb123uy40bviubva08sdyv123&message_id=1&
```

I use method like this and its works fine:

```
@POST("/inboxes")
    Call<InboxesResponse> getInbox(@Header("Authorization") String authorization, @Header("Content-Type") String contentType, @Body RequestBody body);
```

I put token and other parameters into RequestBody:

```
RequestBody body =
                RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), text.toString());
```

All this works fine. But i cant figure out how to  work with file uploading method:

```
Example:
https://adress/fileUpload
POST data:
token=jasdf807gb123uy40bviubva08sdyv123
File body
```

So i need  to use `MultipartBody.Part file` to upload file, but how to combine MultipartBody with RequestBody which contains token? Or how to do this right? i'm confused..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41514375/retrofit-add-header-with-token-and-id possible duplicate

Comment: @karandeepsingh no, its different problem

Comment: how handling of token is different in both cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer was:

```
 @Multipart
    @POST("/fileUpload")
    Call<ResponseBody> uploadFile(@Header("Authorization") String authorization,
                                  @Part("token") RequestBody token,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part file
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

This example worked for me.

```
@Multipart
@Headers("Accept: application/json")
@POST("reports/new")
suspend fun registerReport(@Header("Authorization") access_token:String,
                           @Part("description") description: RequestBody,
                           @Part photo: MultipartBody.Part
) : RegisterResponse
```

As you can see, is not neccesary that the access_token be of type RequestBody, you can pass the header and his type can be String.